# Transferring an object over multiple class instances

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-8

I am thinking of an optimum design pattern which I can use to transfer objects to the methods in different classes other than passing them as arguments.

```
class A{
}

class B{
   public A a;
   public B()
    {
       a = new A();
    }
}

class C
 {
    public void c()
      { 
         //need to access "a" of class B other than passing "a" as argument; 
      }
 }
```

Here, `a` in class A attribute needs to be accessed in many other class methods. Is there an optimum design pattern or any possible way other than passing this object (`a`) as arguments?

Comment: Highly dependent on the actual roles of `A`, `B` and `C`. Can you be more concrete?

Comment: what do you mean by actual roles of A, B and C. Is there any good source to read ?

Comment: It's also dependent of the reason of the class. You could create a singleton if class A could share the same instance globally. Or else you really have to pass it through the constructor.

Comment: @com2ghz thank you for your answer. I will go through singleton design pattern. Is that mean we have only two options to do this?

Comment: Like I said, it depend on the purpose of the class. If class B depends on class A, then class B should have class A as an constructor argument. Please read more about relations between classes.

Comment: My requirement is to not to use "a" as arguments.

Comment: `a = new B();` in your example is not going to compile.

Comment: Oh I've mistakenly typed that. It should be
    a = new A();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say how your program is really structured but two options come to mind:

---

1. Pass an instance of `B` to `C`'s constructor.

---

```
class A {};
class B {
   public A a;
   public B() {
       a = new A();
   }
};
class C {
    public B b;
    public C( B b ) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public void someMethod() { 
        System.out.println( b.a );
    }
};
```

---

2. If only one instance of class `A` ever exists (ie a Singleton). That means that **class** `B` holds an instance of class `A`, **not each instance** of class `B` holds an instance of class `A`.

---

```
class A {};
class B {
   public static final A a = new A();
};
class C {
    public void someMethod() { 
        System.out.println( B.a );
    }
};
```

Comment: Using singleton is the best solution for the question. thank you.